# How to exit the command stream when running php artisan serve?

Tags: laravel

I am suing command prompt on windows. When I run php artisan serve the command prompt enters some kind of command stream where you can not use the command line anymore. How to exit this stream so that I could use the command line? Also, does this mean that exiting this mode will stop serving the app?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a print screen of what is happening and what you want it to do? If you want to stop the current running command, you can press CTRL + C.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`php artisan serve` means you create a server. as long as this server running you can view your created website in browser at `http://localhost:8000` . 
what you said as ’some kind of command stream’ is things that server is serving. 
Yes exiting command prompt will terminate the `php artisan serve` means when you access `http://localhost:8000` there will no website to be seen anymore.

You can terminate the server by Ctrl+c **OR** 
just open another cmd prompt and keep php artisan running

Comment: Mostly you want to keep it working. So open another terminal / command prompt then do next command on another cmd prompt. If production server, use web server Nginx or Apache. Or you can follow @codex answer below, to use web server.

Comment: I just opened another terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem...i simply used xampp shell to run Laravel and used Windows Cmd to perform the rest of my Laravel Commands

Answer (score 0):

Simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
It will come out to prompt state.